# React Router config render authentication

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redirect, router

I am new to React. My Routes.js file look like this

```
const isAuthenticated = true;

export default [
  {
    ...App,
    routes: [
      {
        ...HomePage,
        path: '/',
        exact: true
      },
      {
        path: '/signin',
        ...SignInPage
      },
      {
        path: '/products/:id',
        ...ProductListPage,
        render: props => (!isAuthenticated ? <Redirect to="/signin" /> : <ProductListPage />)
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I get an error though and ProductListPage does not load. Any idea where I am going wrong? Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, what does `...ProductListPage,` do. What is its value

Comment: ProductListPage export default component. If isAuthenticated is false I do not want to show ProductListPage. I added render: to enable this and redirect to Sighin page, but it is not working. Maybe I do not fully understand how ...ProductListPage is working in Routes.js  I get this error "(node:48775) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render". Thanks for your help 